# How to show popup on click leaflet cluster group

Tags: popup, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I have leaflet map with clustergroup  and its working fine. I want to open popup on clustergroup click. On end marker (element) onclick popup is worning fine.

I am able to capture clustergroup click event also but not able to open popup .

```
    //To create cluster
          this.markers =  L.markerClusterGroup(); 

          //On cluster click get all children
          this.markers.on('clusterclick', function (a) {
             this.getClusterData(a.layer.getAllChildMarkers());
            //All children is available of cluster when clicked
        },this);
```

But not able to open popup.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Popup on hovering over cluster group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32067832/popup-on-hovering-over-cluster-group)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32067832/leaflet-markercluster-popup-on-hovering-over-cluster-group).May be it will help someone else. I wasted whole day

```
cluster.on('clustermouseover', function(c) {
          var popup = L.popup()
              .setLatLng(c.layer.getLatLng())
              .setContent(c.layer._childCount +' Locations(click to Zoom)')
              .openOn(map);
          }).on('clustermouseout',function(c){
               map.closePopup();
          }).on('clusterclick',function(c){
               map.closePopup();
          });
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your own answer, which should help others in future.  Could you please also accept it, to make it doubly clear that it works? Thanks